# ASP.Net MVC - Best Datatype Choice for Passing Uploaded File as a parameter to a Service Layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I'm implementing a file upload feature, and want to pass the uploaded file from the controller to a service layer that will do the processing (saving to disc, db updates etc).

I'm following Phil Haacked's example:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

The uploaded file is coming into the Controller's Action method as a parameter of type 
System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase.

I could simply pass this parameter directly to the service layer and call all the convenient methods and properties from it to get the job done, but I would rather not have my service layer have a dependency on System.Web.

Is there a better or "Standard" datatype to chose when passing file content and file metadata (E.G. Filename) in a .Net application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, I've always used a `Stream` or `Byte[]` to transfer files.  Metadata (at least the relevant information I want to keep) are separate parameters.  If you choose to go this route, may I also recommend passing a SHA-1 or another type of hash to verify file integrity.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up wrapping a byte[], metadata and the SHA-1 in an object.